# Markov Jump Process - Transition Probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

For the transition probability of a Markov jump process from state $x$ to $y$ in a small time interval $\Delta t$, what is the meaning of $o(\Delta t)$?
$\alpha$ is a constant $\in[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expressing the fact that the probability to have two or more jumps in the time $\Delta T$ is negligible with respect to $\alpha \Delta t$, and this fact is expressed [in the little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

It could also be expressed in "Big O notation" as $$
\alpha \,\Delta t + O\left( {\Delta t^2 } \right)
$$